# devise + rails 4 + strong parameters inside registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom devise `RegistrationController#create` action that set some attributes behind the scenes (`lat`, `lng`, `city` and `country`). Now that I'm using strong parameters, the problem is that is not recognising these attributes that are inside the create method. It is ok as long as they're in the form page but I want to avoid that since I'm not giving that information to fill, but rather detect it automatically.

```
    def create 
      build_resource(sign_up_params)

      resource.lat = current_latitude
      resource.lng = current_longitude
      resource.city = current_city
      resource.country = current_country_code

      if resource.save
        cookies.delete(:valid_subscription)
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
          sign_up(resource_name, resource)
          respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        else
          set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
          expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        respond_with resource
      end
    end
```

And In `ApplicationController` I have this

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :birthdate, :sex, :interested_list, :lat, :lng)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :lat, :lng)
    end
  end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to whitelist those attributes to pass?

I'm using devise 3.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:create)?

Comment: No, that actually leaves out the ones in the form even If I edit the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was I declared `devise_scope :users do` instead of `devise_scope :user do` on my routes.

Took me almost all day to figure it out!